# popover fails with bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, popover, bootstrap-5

I am trying to reproduce the popover [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/) from Bootstrap 5 but I had a weird behavior of the popover box that does not stay in place.

I just added `data-bs-trigger="hover"`

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marouenbg/txj0hfry/)

Note that when you hover a couple of times the popover jumps around. I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue last year and learned after submitting it as an issue that this is the standard behavior in Bootstrap. It has to do with limiting the number of requests.

There are multiple open issues about it, so you should take it there:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues?q=popover

Workaround suggested here for example:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/32372#issuecomment-749858100

Comment: I remember that was my exact comment too. :D